# Mock or Stub a method in a php parent class

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit, php-7

I am testing a class in phpunit, but I am not mocking it, the class is like that:

```
class MyClass extends ParentClass
{
    public function doSomething($param)
    {
        //do some stuff
        $someValue = $this->anotherMethod(); //this method is defined in the parent class
        //do some other stuff with $someValue

        return $finalValue;
    }
}
```

in the test class I am doing like this

```
public function testDoSomething($param)
{
    $myclass = new MyClass();
    //here I need to control the value of $someValue, as it affects the final value returned
    $res = $myClass->doSomething();

    $this->assertEqual('sonething', res);
}
```

so my question is How can I control the value returned from anotherMethod method? I'd prefer to mock it so it does not call other methods in it

Comment: It isn't very clear, but do you wish to override parent class methods to control them?

Comment: @nice_dev this is exactly my question

Comment: Well, override then. What's stopping you if you want to control the output? You can also call parent:: another Method (); I believe to get the output from parent class and then tweak the output in your overriden method.

Comment: Can you please provide an example? Thanks.

Comment: Does this help? https://3v4l.org/H3A0r

Comment: When you force something like that, sounds like bad design to me. I would rethink the relation parent-child and maybe use aggregation instead of inheritance, or change the behavior of the method, but never force an inside function variable to have specific value that I can't control from outside.

Comment: @FelippeDuarteit is bad design I know. I m adding a test because I added a property to a class, I'm not going to refactor all the application for this.

Comment: @nice_dev I saw the example but I don't see how to test it. I don't want the method anotherMethod to be called because it interacts with the DB.

Comment: @user3174311 Then omit that line and do your thing in the overriden method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could partially mock your class and instrument the methods that you do not want to test, as the following example:

```
    public function testDoSomething()
    {
        /** @var \App\Models\MyClass $classUnderTest */
        $classUnderTest = $this->getMockBuilder(\App\Models\MyClass::class)
            ->onlyMethods(['anotherMethod'])
            ->getMock();

        $classUnderTest->expects($this->once())
            ->method('anotherMethod')
            ->willReturn('mocked-value');

        $this->assertEquals("from-test mocked-value", $classUnderTest->doSomething("from-test"));
    }
```

with the following sources:

**ParentClass**

```
class ParentClass
{

    public function anotherMethod() {
        return "parent-value";
    }
}
```

and **MyClass**

```
class MyClass extends ParentClass
{
    public function doSomething($param)
    {
        //do some stuff
        $someValue = $this->anotherMethod(); //this method is defined in the parent class
        //do some other stuff with $someValue
        $finalValue = $param . ' '. $someValue;
        return $finalValue;
    }
}
```